# Angular mouseover show data tag

Tags: angularjs

I have this button with data="test" when I mouseover the button I want to show the word test in {{Detail}} when I mouse out from the button {{Detail}} should show nothing.

```
</head>
  <body ng-app="">
    <button ng-mouseover="Detail = data" data="test" >MouseOver Me</button>
    Details: {{Detail}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try ng-init="data='test' "

Comment: this does move me along a bit, but when I mouse out from the button {{Detail}} still shows "test"

Comment: Then try using ng-leave for your purpose ...in that ng-leave data="" makes no data visible.

Comment: I tried ng-leave="data=''" and ng-mouseout="data=''" neither work and made a plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/1AbfLQGw4axiCEb7lW7o?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

```
<button ng-mouseover="Detail = data" ng-mouseleave="Detail=''" ng-init="data='test'" >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i think this code is useful for you

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.data="test"
            $scope.hoverIn = function () {
                this.hoverEdit = true;
            };

            $scope.hoverOut = function () {
                this.hoverEdit = false;
            };
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl" >
    <button ng-mouseover="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()" title="{{data}}">MouseOver Me</button>
    Details: <span ng-show="hoverEdit">{{data}}</span>
</body>
</html>
```